# React: how to pass component identity to Redux state

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns, reactjs, architecture

Is it safe to pass `this` to Redux action creator from withing component defined using `React.createClass`?

I have defined the following reducer:

```
const unsavedChangesProtectionReducer = handleActions({
    [ENABLE_UNSAVED_CHANGES_PROTECTION]: (unsavedChangesProtection, action) => ({protected: true}),
    [DISABLE_UNSAVED_CHANGES_PROTECTION]: (unsavedChangesProtection, action) => ({protected: false})},
    {protected: false}
)
```

Multiple components may set/unset the global *state.unsavedChangesProtection.protected* flag, and problem arises from unsetting this flag, as component shouldn't unset it if some other component has set it before this component.

One solution is to check if flag is already set and if not, set it, store the info about component setting the flag in component's internal state, and unset it if internal state states that component has set the flag. However, this violates the DRY principle, as I have to introduce exactly same login in every component.

More generalized solution would be to store the identity of the component which lastly mutated the global state as a member of state itself, so each component can see from the state if it's their change and unset in accordingly. Is this possible to implement in React, as each component are re-initialized when mounted/unmounted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, having a `setBy` property in the reducer could work and you will also have to add the additional logic to the `componentWillUnmount` method for every component that could mutate the flag that would fire the reset `setBy` action  if the component was responsible for the setting/unsetting the flag in the first place (you don't want to leave the reference to the component that was removed from the dom as it will prevent all other components from changing the flag)